# PHP MySQL: Troubleshoot query

Tags: php, mysql

I have what I thought was a straight-forward query, but I cant seem to get it to work. All help appreciated!

**The Tables:**

There are two tables involved: `gallery_meta` and `prm_album`. `The gallery_meta` tbl contains the data for images stored in the file structure. The `prm_album` tbl simply aligns album ID's with album regular-text Names. For both tbls, the field names used in the query are correct.

**The Query:**

In the code below, I first get an array of saved album names. I then check the file structure to see which directories actually contain images. At this point I want to query the db again for a thumbnail for each of the albums that return as positives. It is here that the the process fails.

All I get is a whitescreen, no error reporting whatsoever. The array `$albums` is being filled successfully, and the `$id` variable is being passed to the `$q` query. `$pattern` is simply the file path to the parent directory where the album directories are stored.

```
            //Get album names from db
            $albums = array(); 
            $q="SELECT ID, Name FROM prm_album WHERE 1";
            $sql=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $album = $r['Name'];
                $album_dir = $pattern.$album.'/';

                //check which albums actually contain images (dividing to account for thumbs, med, lrg.)
                $filecount = count(glob($album_dir.'*'))/3;

                //if images found, put album in array
                if($filecount >= 1) {
                    $albums[ $r['ID'] ] = $filecount;
                }
            }

            foreach($albums as $id => $filecount) {     
                $q="SELECT m.AlbumID, m.FileName, m.FileExt,
                        m.LegacyName, m.IsDefault,
                        p.Name
                        FROM gallery_meta AS m
                            LEFT JOIN prm_album AS p
                                ON m.AlbumID = p.ID

                        WHERE m.AlbumID = $id
                            AND Public = 1
                            ORDER BY IsDefault DESC
                            LIMIT 0,1";

                $sql=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
                while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    $album=$r['Name'].'/';
                    $legacyname=$r['LegacyName'];
                    $filename=$r['FileName'].'-sm.';
                    $ext=$r['FileExt'];

                    echo '<img src="'$pattern.$album.$filename.$ext.'" />'.$legacyname.'<br/>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have `error_reporting` turned on and `display_errors` turned on? The only output I see in your code is the `echo '<img src..'`, which will only output if there were rows returned from the `$q` query.

Comment: Did you test your query in a MySQL client to verify that it does in fact return a row?

Comment: @Michael Tried it in the PHP MyAdmin console - worked fine. I really can;t see what's wrong with it. If I remove the query within the foreach statement, the page processes no problem. With the query - white screen. Even with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`!

Comment: check your server log for the error

Comment: @Cfreak Last few errors are for a missing robots.txt file. No mention of the page i'm working on...

Comment: Sure that display_errors is set? The line with the echo misses a concatenating point before $pattern. Should have thrown an unexpected whatever error.

Comment: try put `echo('debugging');` in the while loop to know if there were iteration or `echo(mysql_num_rows($sql))` before the while loop

Comment: @32bitfloat Works! (put it as an answer). The concatenation was the problem. Good eyes :) I'm verrrrry puzzled by the error reporting - could have solved a lot of hassle. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo '<img src="'$pattern.$album.$filename.$ext.'" />'.$legacyname.'<br/>';
```

to

```
echo '<img src="'.$pattern.$album.$filename.$ext.'" />'.$legacyname.'<br/>';
```

The first dot was missing. And always set these lines on top of your script =)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points ${id} can be written this way in a string and maybe needs \"${id}\" 
but more likely
**Put all of the$q string on one line in the PHP code or the parser interpreter could trip over the newline characters in it and certainly the sql will.**

```
$q="SELECT m.AlbumID, m.FileName, m.FileExt, m.LegacyName, m.IsDefault, p.Name FROM gallery_meta AS m LEFT JOIN prm_album AS p ON m.AlbumID = p.ID WHERE m.AlbumID = $id AND Public = 1 ORDER BY IsDefault DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

You should be able to test that on a command line into a database first too(bit of wisdom).

Comment: Tried it all in one line (although I have loads of multiple line queries throughout the site) with no luck. Also tried escaping the `$id` but no change there either. As noted above, the query works fine when passed directly to the db via the console. Thanks though!